# Validating an ASP.Net textbox as not empty but allowing whitespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, validation

I have an ASP.Net 2.0 textbox which I need to be validated as having *some* content, but where whitespace alone is valid input.

A required field validator seems to reject a pure whitespace input as invalid. A regular expression validator won't fire at all on empty content.

Is there a simpler way round this than using a custom validator control?

Comment: Actually, according to the docs the custom validator won't fire on empty content either.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: custom validator is the only way.

Comment: Hmm. So a required field validator can't be used because it'll see whitespace as nothing and neither custom nor regular expression validators can be used because they won't try to validate nothing... Is there any way of chaining validators together that I've missed, say getting the firing of a RequiredFieldValidator to then fire a subsequent RegularExpressionValidator that makes the final call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options, neither which use the automagic FUD.

1. Create a new type of validator that does not Trim() prior to validation - this is the long pole and most time consuming
2. Use JavaScript to validate and control the postback yourself (assuming client validation)
3. Server side validate (or use AJAX for validation) - Potential negative is waiting to validate until a postback

I can't think of any other options.